# Using Min and max function inside a function

Tags: r, function, min

I have created a function which uses 2 variables to do grouping and uses third variable to create min and max for each groups. But the min and max function gives wrong output. It gives the minimum and maximum for entire dataset and not for each group.

```
myfunction= function(x,a,b,column) {
  temp=group_by(x,x[[a]],x[[b]])
   Score=summarise(temp,Totals=n(),Mnscore=min(x[[c]]),Mxscore=max(x[[c]]))
 return(Score)
}

myfunction(dataset,"a","b","c")


Actual Results:
a b Totals  Min Max
1 1  10     15  50
1 2  20     15  50
1 3  30     15  50

Expected results:
a b Totals  Min Max
1 1  10     20  48
1 2  20     21  49
1 3  30     15  50
```

Comment: you need to learn about lazy evaluations and quasi quotations in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to write a function, you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
myfunction= function(x,a,b,column) 
  {
  column <- enquo(column)
  vars <- enquos(a,b)
  x %>% 
    group_by(!!!vars) %>% 
    summarise(Totals=n(),Mnscore=min(!!c),Mxscore=max(!!column))
}
```

then call this inputing a,b,c as symbols and not characters

```
myfunction(dataset,a,b,column)
```

Comment: `rlang 0.4.0` [added a new curly-curly operator](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/), which is effectively a shortcut for `!!enquo()`. So, now you can just do `... %>% summarize( Totals=n(), Mnscore = min({{column}}), Mxscore=max({{column}}) )`. (Also, it is generally not advisable to use `c` as a variable name because of its conflict with the built-in `c()`.)

Comment: @ArtemSokolov true its not advisable to use c.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data.table` package if you want a very effective way to solve your problem. Try the following minimal reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(20191011L)

data <- data.table(
  V1 = letters[sample(3, 20, TRUE)],
  V2 = letters[sample(3, 20, TRUE)],
  V3 = runif(20)
)

fun <- function(data, groups, target){

  data[, .(min=min(get(target)), max=max(get(target))), mget(groups)]

}

fun(data, c("V1", "V2"), "V3")

##     V1 V2        min       max
##  1:  b  c 0.20653948 0.4618063
##  2:  a  a 0.09560888 0.3347064
##  3:  b  b 0.75071480 0.7507148
##  4:  c  a 0.66410519 0.8258410
##  5:  c  c 0.01303751 0.7635212
##  6:  a  b 0.04770186 0.6332439
##  7:  b  a 0.25069813 0.9008885
```

Comment: I want to create as a function since I have to use that function multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, did not saw you asked for a function. I edit my answer to implement it as a function.

Comment: I am getting this error : Error in .(min = min(get(target)), max = max(get(target))) : 
  could not find function "."

Comment: Make sure your data is a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(dplyr)

result = dataset %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(a,b) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Totals = n(),
                   Mnscore = min(c),
                   Mxscore = max(c))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: how is this a function?

Comment: @Onyambu, it's not but OP does not necessarily need a function here.

Comment: I want to create as a function since I have to use that function multiple times.